# Cocoa Touch, set transform identity equal to current transform state

Tags: ios, cocoa, touch, cgaffinetransform

How do I change the transformIdentity. How do we set the transform "zero", or alter the transformIdentity of a view to the current state of the transform of said view.

In other words, I want to scale a view, and then set the current state (say scale of 2.5) to the default scale of the view (scale of 1).

example code:

```
   view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 2.5);
```

pseudo code for what I want to do:

```
   view.transform = setTransformIdentityTo:view.currentState;
```

If I understand correctly transformIdentity is the state at which a scale would be 1, or a rotation would be zero, the default "zero" transform.

NOTE: The reason I want to do this is so that I can set a negative scale transform on only one axis of the view and alway get a flipped view relative to the last state of the view before the flip was invoked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CGAffineTransformIdentity` does reset a view or layer to its original, untransformed state, and thus cannot be redefined.
But if you want your "personal" reset transform, e.g. with a different scale, why don't you simply define it, e.g. by using `CGAffineTransform myCGAffineTransformIdentity = CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformMakeScale (sx,sy);`, and apply it to your views?

Answer (score 2):

```
selectedSticker.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to reset the transform, I want to set identity  to be equal to the current state of the view. I edited my question.

Comment: @Mrwolfy: “Identity” is a mathematical concept: the multiplier that performs no change. You don't get to redefine that, not in Quartz nor elsewhere.

Comment: thanks, I didn't really understand that well. In certain applications, like graphic programs for instance from my experience we have "freeze transforms" or other operations that basically set the zero translate, one scale, zero rotation to the current state of the object, view or geometry in question. That is what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this works for what I want to do:

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 2.5);

view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(selectedSticker.transform, trans);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, if you want to have your view still be transformed even when its own transform is the identity transform, is to put it inside another view that is transformed. Give the outer view the transform you want for your default; the inner view is the one where you do the actual work.

So, let's say you want your “identity” to be scaled by 2× horizontally. You set your outer view's transform to that transform, and leave it that way, and leave the inner view untransformed. When you want to add further transformation, you add it to the inner view, and when you want to reset it back to your default, you set the inner view's transform back to (true) identity. Your inner view will still scaled (or whatever) by the outer view's transform.

---

Note: I tried this briefly and found that (a) Auto Layout barfed on it, (b) scaling is outward from the anchor point, which means my outer view's horizontal scale pushed my inner view a little bit out-of-bounds, and (c) changing the outer view's anchor point to `CGPointZero` produced even further hilarity.

So, while this is theoretically a nice, simple, elegant solution, it may actually be more problematic than it's worth, in which case I recommend [what Reinhard Männer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16129182/30461).